# Email Footer Issue jira

Tags: jira

I am able to recive and send emails properly.

Email footer content is displaying **"template.footer.text"** instead of text.

please provide suggestions.

what are files i need to edit and location for files.

regards,
tousif shaikh.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with Jira but I'd speculate you're missing a template file which probably live here:

```
atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/templates/email/html/includes/
atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/templates/email/text/includes/
```

You'll probably have better luck at the Jira forums which seems to have been based on yours truly :)

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/

Comment: hi thanks for your suggestions i am looking forward to get the footer.vm changes in html and text file.     below my email contents its showing template.footer.text text in footer so i want how can i work on that.